# How to get 3 day moving average in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: users, traffic.

The first table consists of the users information (id, name, user_type) .

The second table consists of the time of each visit to the website:(user_id, visited_on, time_spent).

Users Table:

| ID | Name | User_tpe |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | matt | user |
| 2 | john | user |
| 3 | louis | admin |

Traffic Table:

| user_id | visited_on | time_spent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-05-01 | 15 |
| 2 | 2019-05-02 | 20 |
| 2 | 2019-05-03 | 10 |

Trying to write a query to show the 3 day moving average of time spent on the website for users.user_type='user'. Also, avg_time_spent must have 4 decimal digits and rounded off.

I am stuck here and trying to figure out:

```
Select t.visited_on, avg(time_spent)over(

partition by user_id order by visited_on

range between interval 2 day PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW

) as avg_time_spent

from traffic t join users u on u.id=t.user_id

where u.user_type='user';
```

Could any one please help what I am missing here

Comment: This is obviously an assignment [Asked here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71277665/computing-3-day-moving-average-sql). Crazily its the exact same query.  **Is this a duplicate account ?**

Comment: And here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74157325/how-to-get-3-days-moving-average-in-mysql

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - Please flag to close it